# On an elliptic curve, canonical divisors and principal divisors are the same thing, right?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

I'm reading about elliptic curves. Let $K$ denote a field $E$ denote an elliptic curve over $K$. From what I gather:

- A *principal divisor* of $E$ is a divisor of the form $\mathrm{div}(f)$ for some $f \in \overline{K}(E)$.
- A *canonical divisor* of $E$ is a divisor of the form $\mathrm{div}(\omega)$ for some non-zero differential $\omega \in \Omega_E$.
- Every elliptic curve has an invariant differential $\omega$ with no zeroes or poles.
- Hence $0$ is a canonical divisor of $E$.
- The divisors of any two non-zero differential forms differ by a principal divisor.

> **Question.** Does this mean that, on an elliptic curve, canonical and principal mean the same thing? If not, what have I misunderstood?

Comment: Yes this is correct.

Comment: A canonical divisor is the divisor of a *meromorphic* differential. On a complex torus $X = \mathbb{C}/(\mathbb{Z}+\tau \mathbb{Z})$ then $dz$ is an holomorphic differential so that $f(z)dz$ is a meromorphic differential for any meromorphic function $f \in \mathbb{C}(X)$. And there is no more holomorphic differential because the genus is $1$.